# Two matrix A ,B which are Row equivalence

Tags: matrix-equations

I have two matrix $A,B$ which are row equivalence,I have to find a matrix $P$ such that $A=PB$ .

I try solving that by saying that $P$ is  elementary procedure therefore I try find which elementary procedure i need to do for going from $B$ to $A$. I try to guess it, but i am sure there is a way to do so,and I do not know how.

I DUNNO WHY IT doesnt make space, $B, A \in \mathbb{R}^{ 3\times 2}$ .

I need to find $A=PB$
thank you

$$B= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -3 \\  -4 & 1 \\ 6 & 9 \end{bmatrix},  A= \begin{bmatrix}  -4 & 1 \\ -2 & -10 \\ 12 & 18 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/5023/306553 mathjax help in typing matrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break down this into smaller problems:

It is known that the reduced row echelon form is 
$$R=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
Task $1$:
find a nonsingular matrix $Q$ such that $QA=R$, record down the elementary operations that you use.

Task $2$:
find a nonsingular matrix $W$ such that $WB=R$, record dow the elementary operations that you use.

Task $3$:
Since $Q$ is invertible,  $QA=R$ and $WB=R$, conclude that $QA=WB$ and $A=Q^{-1}W$.

Task $4$:
Compute $P=Q^{-1}W$.

Edit:

**How to find $W$ such that $WB=R$.**

Let $E_1$ be the operation $4R_1+R_2$, i.e. multiply the first row by $4$ and add to row $2$. the second row become $[0, -11]$

$E_2$ be the operation $-\frac{1}{11}R_2$. The second row become $[0, 1]$

$E_3$ be the operation $3R_2+R_1$. The first row become $[1, 0]$.

$E_4$ be the operation $-6R_1+R_3$. The third row become $[0,9]$

$E_5$ be the operation $-9R_2+R_3$. The third row become $[0,0]$.

$E_5E_4E_3E_2E_1B=R$, here $W=E_5E_4E_3E_2E_1$.

Similarly $Q$ in $QA=R$ can be expressed as elementary operations, $Q=F_m \ldots F_1$.

$$Q^{-1}W=(F_m \ldots F_1)^{-1}(E_5 \ldots E_1)=F_1^{-1}\ldots F_m^{-1}E_5\ldots E_1$$

To compute $P$, it suffices to perform the operations $F_1^{-1}\ldots F_m^{-1}E_5\ldots E_1$ on the identity matrix.

Comment: I dont understand,i do here with my example

Comment: are you able to find the matrix $Q$ and $W$? also in your question, did I understand correctly that $B=\begin{bmatrix}  1 &-3 \\ -4 &1 \\6 & 9 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Yes this ,thanks

Comment: are you able to find $Q$ and $W$?

Comment: Reduced row encholn you mean canocial form?

Comment: I cant who is P here

Comment: $P=Q^{-1}W$, find $Q$, find its inverse, then find $W$, then you can compute $P$

Comment: The condition in Task 3 is redundant. You’ve already stated in Task 1 that $Q$ is nonsingular.

Comment: @MosheLevy Recall that if you augment a matrix with an appropriately-sized identity matrix and row-reduce, you end up with the matrix that transforms your original into the rref. That is, row-reducing $\begin{bmatrix}A\mid I_3\end{bmatrix}$ produces $\begin{bmatrix}R\mid Q\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Yes thank you ,is there a faster way to do so?